# Mesh fails to create

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a road mechanic but when I instantiate a mesh, it fails to even create.

I have a version where it's a mesh created in the script(commented) and it works as intended, but when i switch to the instantiated, the roadStart ray and roadend ray both work. I followed a tutorial by quill18 to get a sense of where to go. But I got to a point where I got so frustrated I just copy and pasted and it still failed to work.

```
bool ClickLoc(out Vector3 point)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    print(ray);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        point = hit.point;
        return true;
    }
    point = Vector3.zero;
    return false;
}
void CreateRoad(Vector3 roadStart, Vector3 roadEnd)
{
    float width = 1;
    float length = Vector3.Distance(roadStart, roadEnd);

    if (length < .5)
    {
        return;
    }

    GameObject road = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabRoad);
   // GameObject road = new GameObject ("road", typeof(MeshRenderer),typeof(MeshFilter));
    road.transform.position = roadStart + new Vector3(0, 0.01f, 0);

    road.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, roadEnd - roadStart);
    Debug.Log(road.transform.rotation.eulerAngles);

    Vector3[] vertices = {
            new Vector3(0,      0, -width/2),
            new Vector3(1, 0, -width/2),
            new Vector3(1, 0,  width/2),
            new Vector3(0,      0,  width/2)
        };

    int[] triangles = {
            1, 0, 2,    // triangle 1
            2, 0, 3     // triangle 2
        };


    Vector2[] uv = {
            new Vector2(0, 0),
            new Vector2(1, 0),
            new Vector2(1, 1),
            new Vector2(0, 1)
        };

    Vector3[] normals = {
            Vector3.up,
            Vector3.up,
            Vector3.up,
            Vector3.up
        };

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.uv = uv;
    mesh.normals = normals;

    MeshFilter mesh_filter = road.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    MeshRenderer mr = road.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    mesh_filter.mesh = mesh;


}
Vector3 roadStart;
Vector3 roadEnd;
void Update()
{


    if (yes == true & Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
    {


        ClickLoc(out roadStart);

    }


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        ClickLoc(out roadEnd);
        print(click);
        if (roadStart.magnitude != 0)
        {
            CreateRoad(roadStart, roadEnd);
        }

       // if (click == false)
         //   {
           //     CreateRoad(roadStart, roadEnd);
             //   mid = true;
            //}
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        click = false;
    }


}
```

}

The road created will start at the center of the map and end at my mouse position

Comment: `it fails to even create` could you explain better what exactly doesn't work? is happening nothing? Are you sure the according methods get called and executed? Any errors/warnings? Where/When is `yes` set to `true`? Note that you should use the bool operator `&&` not the binary `&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and copy your CreateRoad() method and took a quad, cleared the mesh from meshfilter and used that as the roadPRefab and it works. Think it might be as derHugo says; that some portion of your code does not get called.